# What is this mixed random variable’s variance?

Tags: variance, mixed-random-variable

X ∼ Uniform(a,b), a<b (Discrete) where f(x)=1/n where n=b-a+1 and Y ∼ Uniform(c,d), c<d (Continuous) where g(y)=1/d-c. X and Y are independent. Let z = x - y. I was able to find the E(Z), however I couldn’t derive its variance. What is the Var(z)? I couldn’t write the integral from of its variance to begin evaluating. How do I write its variance with integral and sigma? Is the following process accurate?

[image]

Comment: Please do not start a new thread when you want to modify your original question: just edit the original.  This preserves the comments and other information.